# Do <header>, <nav>, <main>, etc have any impact if no styles are assigned to them?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

If I have no:

```
nav {
    color: red;
}
```

and use it as `<nav>`, i.e.with no class= or style=, does it have any impact on layout and/or style?

Reading it, I assume there is no impact (same for the other [Semantic Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)). And of course, marking parts with these then help for accessibility, etc.

Comment: What kinf of impact are you talking about?

Comment: Layout, yes; they'll act as `<div>`s.

Comment: @j08691 any impact whatsoever. I've got them in there to provide the semantic markup. But I want the rendered page to be identical to their not being there.

Comment: @ceejayoz like a <div> with no style/class is fine. All that means (I believe) is what it contains needs to be block of content. And what's in them is that.

Comment: As ceejayoz noted, alone all they are are block level elements.

Comment: If either of you write that as an answer, happy to accept it. thanks

Comment: Here is a [list of all block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). These all "act" the same if no styles are applied - in terms of the box model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "block box" and "block-level element"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090912/what-is-the-difference-between-block-box-and-block-level-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These html elements that you are listing (`header`, `nav`, `main`) all have the same styling as a normal `div` when rendered.

The only purpose of their naming being different to a `div` is for semantic reason which is useful for screen readers or other developers reading your code.

It will not affect the styling at all.